# WebCore WebCore::GraphicsContext3D::reshape(int, int)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, crashlytics, crash-reports

I am getting this report from crashlystics and, what does it means and how I can solve this issue to stop crashing my music application

http://prntscr.com/kbl58s

Screenshot of App delegate:

1. http://prntscr.com/kbm77y
2. http://prntscr.com/kbm7q4
3. http://prntscr.com/kbm7xh
4. http://prntscr.com/kbm83a

//Application background state

5. http://prntscr.com/kbm8dn
6. http://prntscr.com/kbm8nf

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot of crash infos, the key reason is OpenGL rendering on app background state.

So observe app's state, stop OpenGL rendering while it is going to enter background 
and resume OpenGL rendering while it's coming back to foreground.

How to observe this?

1. the methods in `UIApplicationDelegate`: 
   `applicationDidEnterBackground:` and `applicationWillEnterForeground`
2. Two system notifications: `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`
3. Check `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState;`. Stop openGL unless applicationState is `UIApplicationStateActive`

Comment: "Stop OpenGL rendering" I have not used any openGL ,Please check this SS of my ApP delegate in my questions I have updated